# Find clusters by edge definition in arangodb

Tags: arangodb

Does arangodb provide a utility to list clusters for a given edge definition?

E.g. Given the graph:

```
Tyrion ----sibling---> Cercei ---sibling---> Jamie

Bran ---sibling--> Arya ---sibling--> Jon
```

I'd want something like the following:

```
my_graph._getClusters({edge: "sibling"}) -> [  [Tyrion, Cercei, Jamie], [Bran, Arya, Jon]  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have a graph named `siblings`, then the following query will find all paths in the graph that are connected by edges with type `sibling` and that have a (path) length of 3. This should match the example data you provided:

```
LET options = {  
  followEdges: [ 
    { type: 'sibling' } 
  ] 
}
FOR i IN GRAPH_TRAVERSAL('sibling', { }, "outbound", options)
  FILTER LENGTH(i) == 3
  RETURN i[*].vertex._key
```

Omitting or adjusting the `FILTER` will also find longer or shorter paths in the graph.